# How can I approach meaning of these in bold?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://blogs.economictimes.indiatimes.com/Undertheinfluence/going-going-gurgaon/)

> All that the proud, rooted people of Gurgaon-Gurugram now need to develop is a ’Gram Culture – apart from visiting malls and believing that microbreweries are really **art galleries, minus the art.** But then, cutting-edge **brand-hurrahing** irony that is indigenous will have to be dredged up from somewhere outside Madmen and Mad magazines.

The first one I think is a metaphor.What it intends to say I don't know.Also, a single apostrophe before **Gram** appears to be a typo.

Comment: I'm sure that apostrophe in **'Gram** is deliberate. It's the same principle as that in [earlier written instances](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/05/frisco.html) of **'Frisco** (dropping the first part of *San Francisco*). Your (ridiculously pretentious) writer thinks it's a "cool" style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'Gram culture

Apostrophes can be used to mark abbreviations and contractions. So 'Gram is an abbreviation since the full name of the city is "Gurugram". Calling it 'Gram Culture is fitting since it calls attention to the name change from -gaon to -gram.

So the author believes they need to develop a culture that the author is calling 'Gram Culture.

Now, part of the sense of "culture" here is

> [culture](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/culture)
>   **a** :  enlightenment and excellence of taste acquired by intellectual and aesthetic training
>   **b** :  acquaintance with and taste in fine arts, humanities, and broad aspects of science as distinguished from vocational and technical skills

In other words, there should be a level sophistication associated with this so-called Gram Culture. 
By writing

> believing that microbreweries are really art galleries, minus the art.

I believe the author is making a joke. He is saying that microbreweries **do not** count as art. So having them as part of the Gram Culture does not really add sophistication to the culture.

> brand-hurrahing

One of the definitions of *hurrah* is

> [hurrah](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hurrah)
>   hubbub; commotion; fanfare

It is noun, but by writing "brand-hurrahing", I think the author is saying something like "making a commotion about brand(s)", or simply "brand advertising".

Comment: I disagree about the apostrophe being part of a pair (scare quotes). It's just a "cool" shortening of ***Gurugram*** (made more "natural" by the fact that after the rename, those last 4 characters can now be seen as "iconic")..

Comment: Actually, I realized that right when I posted and add a note about it.